# How to parse HTML text and modify some HTML nodes in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have already searched this subject but I could not find any good answers.

Suppose I have a XLST paramater call $HtmlText that is assigned a block of htmltext:

```
<xsl:param name="HtmlText">
    <xsl:value-of select="/rootxmldata/somehtmltext" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:param>
```

And the HTML text assigned to $HtmlText paramter has several DIV elements such as the following:

```
<div id="item1">
    <div class="test1"><span>item 1</span></div>
</div>
<div id="item2">
    <div class="test2"><span>item 2</span></div>
</div>
<div id="item3">
    <div class="test3"><span>item 3</span></div>
</div>
```

Here is my question:

Is it possible use XLST 1.0 to parse these HTML nodes and delete or modify a DIV node based on its ID?

Any information or a simple example would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show the input XML document with the `somehtmltext` node.

Comment: Well, which Xslt 1.0 processor on which platform are you using? And the sample which you have shown looks as if it were parseable as an XML fragment, as attributes values are quoted, end tags are there. Depending on the XSLT processor parsing of XML might be relatively easy using an extension, parsing HTML on the other hand is not something you can easily plug in.

Comment: Michael,hor257k,  I do not have a input XML document per se because the XSLT in question is running on a AspDotNetStoreFront hosted web site site.  Any XML data would come from the site's database.  I was hoping that I do not need to provide any specific XML input document to get a simple example on how to parse a block of HTML code in XSLT.  I have a feeling that it is not a simple task because after whole days of research on teh web, I simply can not find any example.

Comment: Martin, the web site I'm working on is a AspDotNetStoreFront platform so it should be using ASP.NET's XSLT 1.0 processor.  I have a feeling that parsing a block of HTML text using XSLT may not be a simple task.  If it's something difficult, I will probably research alternative approach to accomplish what I need to do.  Thank you.

Comment: Well, the thing is it's not quite clear what you're working with: is it XML or is it text. I suggest you run an *identity transform* on the input and post the result.

Comment: Michael, the XSLT parameter is assigned a block of HTML text.  Just assume you are accessing a specific XML node that contains a block of text that happens be HTML markup.  But since HTML text does not mean anything to XSLT processor, you cannot really parse HTML nodes directly.  But I was hoping XSLT may have some tricks to "import" a block of HTML text and manipulate them as if they are XML nodes.  Before I posted my question, I was 80% certain that is not possible.  After further research on the web today, I'm pretty sure that is not possible.  I think we can close this thread now.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know what "HTML text" means. XML/XSLT have no such concept. The real question here is whether the input is **marked-up text** (and for this purpose, there is very little difference between XML markup and HTML markup - none in your example), or is the markup **escaped** in the form of `&lt;div&gt;`. Your use of `disable-output-escaping` makes this distinction impossible.

Comment: If the input is indeed escaped, then by all means do look for an alternative approach, because parsing escaped markup (as text) is very tedious. AFAIK, the only real cure is to save the unescaped text as a new document and then parse it in another XSLT process.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Which extension do you have in mind?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, with MSXML it is possible to write an extension function with JScript or VBScript that parses X(HT)ML and in the .NET world with XslCompiledTransform it is possible to write extension functions or use extension objects making use of the .NET framework API (XPathDocument or XmlDocument) to parse X(HT)ML or maybe even HTML (using HTMLAgilityPack, but never tried that).